# How to navigate GridView into another page in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, gridview

So, here is my code for the GridView. I'm already tried to use InkWell but it does not navigate to the page that is specified. I don't know what is the problem as I am new in coding world. I also try restructure the code but as I said I am new so the code always got some error here and there. I hope i can get some help in solving this problem. Thank you all.

```
class _DashboardState extends State<Dashboard> {
Material myItems(IconData icon, String heading, int color) {
return Material(
  color: Colors.white,
  elevation: 14.0,
  shadowColor: Color(0x802196F3),
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
  child: Center(
    child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[

              //text
              Center(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Text(
                    heading,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: new Color(color),
                      fontSize: 20.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),

              //icon
              Material(
                color: new Color(color),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24.0),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                  child: Icon(
                    icon,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    size: 30.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

}

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text(
      'Dashboard',
      style: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
    ),
  ),
  body: Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
    child: StaggeredGridView.count(
    crossAxisCount: 1,
    mainAxisSpacing: 12.0,
    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 8.0),
    children: <Widget>[
      myItems(
        Icons.report, 
        "Report", 
        0x802196F3),
      myItems(
        Icons.insert_chart, 
        "Chart", 
        0x802196F3),
      myItems(
        Icons.format_list_numbered, 
        "Ranking", 
        0x802196F3),
    ],
    staggeredTiles: [
      StaggeredTile.extent(1, 130),
      StaggeredTile.extent(1, 130),
      StaggeredTile.extent(1, 130)
     ],
    ),
   ),
  );
 }
}
```

Comment: Where did you try to `push` another page?

Comment: so under my code, i insert and Inkwell like this, then continue with the child: myItems
children <widget> [
InkWell(onTap: () {
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/Menu")
},

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried adding an Inkwell with a simple print statement to one of your tiles and it worked, clicking on report prints hello in the console.

```
children: <Widget>[
    InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        print('hello!');
      },
      child: myItems(Icons.report, "Report", 0x802196F3),
    ),
    myItems(Icons.insert_chart, "Chart", 0x802196F3),
    myItems(Icons.format_list_numbered, "Ranking", 0x802196F3),
  ],
),
```

Comment: if to navigate to other page, is it correct to do it like this? 
onTap: () {
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/Menu");

Comment: Yes, it'd be good if you also showed your routing code. If it doesn't work maybe it's because of that.

Comment: for my routing code i declare it on my main page which is like this
 routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
        "/DashboardPage": (BuildContext context) => new Dashboard(),
        "/Menu": (BuildContext context) => new Menu(),

Comment: you're using quite an old version of the syntax but it should work. I made a demo based on your code, and it successfully goes to the other page: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/wVwTJVTBwY/